# Is there any library for react native to implement end to end encryption in chat like Signal protocol?

Tags: react-native, end-to-end-encryption, signal-protocol

I'm trying to build a real time chat app with react native, nodejs and mongodb. I already built the regular chat app but I need to add end to end encryption (E2EE). I tried to use libsignal-protocol javascript library ([libsignal-protocol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsignal-protocol)) built by Signal Messenger but library is not working with react native since it need to import via index.htm file as a script. I tried to install via NPM but it's  giving import error. Now I need a library to implement E2EE in my react native app.

Comment: @JavohirMirzoFazliddinov Nope, manually used RSA encryption with NPM package.